# Why am I getting the wrong values?

Tags: python-3.x

```
player_list= {'peter':0, 'karel':0}

naam = input("Welke speler moet een score + 1 krijgen?")
for key, value in player_list.items():
    player_list[naam] = value + 1

print(player_list)
```

Can someone explain me I why get the correct value whenever I enter "peter" but not when I enter "karel"?

Comment: Why do you iterate over all players?

Comment: You haven't explained what the correct value is. Further, you should take the time to understand what every single individual part in your code is doing before you ask here, and since your code is extremely short you will also have figured this out at that point - ie this shouldn't be asked here at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that you'd like to increment dict value of the key which is same as the string that user provides via `input`. Ask yourself, do you really need to iterate over dict items to do such thing? Dict is key-value structure, and you can access value of the key whenever you provide this key directly.

```
>>> player_list = {'peter':0, 'karel':0}
>>> player_list['peter']
0
```

Setting value to the existing dict key is easy. All you need to do is:

```
>>> player_list['peter'] = 3
>>> player_list['peter']
3
```

If you'd like to increment value for 'peter' you need to take whatever is stored under 'peter' and add one, but there is no need to iterate over dict items to do that. Like with any other variable, dict element is kind of placeholder for some space of memory that you can access via that placeholder. So in case of any variable you'd do something as:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x = x + 1 # or x += 1 for short
```

...and in case of dict element, you can do the same:

```
>>> player_list['peter'] = player_list['peter'] + 1 # or:
>>> player_list['peter'] += 1
```

If you're curious why your current code doesn't work as you expected, run your code using debugger or just add print function:

```
for key, value in player_list.items():
    print("Current key: {}, current value: {}".format(key, value))
    player_list[naam] = value + 1
```

In fact, it's always good to use some debugging tools whenever you don't know why your code execution is different than your expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I copied the code from another stackoverflow question and I thought it was the correct way.